# How do you know if two elements from different array lists collide?

Tags: java, processing

Right now, we're programming a shoot-em-up game where you play as an aeroplane whose task it is to shoot the enemies of course. We have two different classes, one for the bullets and another one for the enemies. We are having trouble with checking if these two elements collide with each other.

We've already attempted to compare the x- and y-coordinates of these two elements, but that didn't seem to work.

```java
void hit() {
    for(int i = 0; i < Bullet.size(); i++) {
        Bullet bullet = (Bullet) Bullet.get(i);
        Enemy enemy = (Enemy) enemies.get(i);
        if(bullet.x < enemy.x + enemy.l 
           && enemy.x > enemy.x - enemy.l 
           && enemy.y < bul.y) {
            enemy.health -= 1;
            println("Hit");
            if(enemy.health <= 0) {
                enemy = null;
                // enemies.remove(i);
            }
        }      
    }
}
```

bul is our array list for the bullets and enm is for the enemies

Comment: add a method 'isHit(Bullet bullet)' to your enemy class and test it

Comment: You will need two `for-loop` for cross checking two set of data.

Comment: Please call your "bul" variable "bullet" and you "enm" variable "enemy", this is really hard to read and understand! Also, in video games, a common name for "enemy" is "foe". ;-)
What is enm.l?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have only one `for-loop` when checking collision. So you are actually checking if bullet #1 is hitting enemy #1. You will need two `for-loop` to check each bullet against each enemy.

```
void hit() {

    for(int i = 0; i < Bullet.size(); i++)
    {
        Bullet bul = (Bullet) Bullet.get(i);

        for(int j=0; j<enemies.size(); j++){
            Enemy enm = (Enemy)enemies.get(j);
            if(bul.x < enm.x + enm.l && bul.x > enm.x - enm.l && enm.y<bul.y)
            {
                enm.health -= 1;
                println("Hit");
                if(enm.health <= 0)
                {
                  enm = null;
                //  enemies.remove(i);
                }
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check every bullet with every enemy. In your code you are checking first bullet with first enemy.

```
for(int i = 0; i < Bullet.size(); i++){
Bullet bul = (Bullet) Bullet.get(i);
for(int j=0;j<enemies.size();j++){
Enemy enm = (Enemy)enemies.get(j);
if(bul.x < enm.x + enm.l && bul.x > enm.x - enm.l && enm.y<bul.y)
{
enm.health -= 1;
println("Hit");
if(enm.health <= 0)
{
  enm = null;
//  enemies.remove(i);
}
}  
}    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ONE: I would expect to find lists of enemies and bullets somewhere. From your code I guess you've hidden the "bullets" list in the Bullet class. I'd strongly recommend you to *not* do this.

TWO: You may want to put the collision test into its own method. You can get the distance of two points using the *pythagorean theorem*: (enemy.x - bullet.x)^2 + (enemy.y - bullet.y)^2 = distance^2. I have no idea, what your enm.l property is, but it slightly looks like a dimension thing. I assume a radius property for enemies here instead:

```
boolean areColliding(final Enemy enemy, final Bullet bullet) {
  final int dX= enemy.x - bullet.x;
  final int dY= enemy.y - bullet.y;
  return (dX * dX) + (dY * dY) < e(enemy.radius * enemy.radius);
}
```

THREE: Your method is called "hit", but it does not "hit" anything. Instead it applies the effects of collisions to enemies. The name should reflect that. I am using an *iterator* to iterate over all enemies and the *for-each-loop* to iterate all bullets in this example. The iterator is need for easy removing the current element from the underlying list:

```
void applyCollisions() {
  final Iterator<Enemy> enemyIterator = enemies.iterator();
  while (enemyIterator.hasNext()) {
    final Enemy eachEnemy = enemyIterator.next();

    for (final Bullet eachBullet : bullets) {
      if (areColliding(eachEnemy, eachBullet) {
        enemy.health--;
        println("Hit");
        if (enemy.health <= 0) {
          enemyIterator.remove();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're currently checking Bullet(i) against Enemy(i), effectively only checking each bullet against one enemy.
I am surprised this doesn't crash because of an out of bounds index when there are less enemies than bullets.
As other answers have already said, solve this by having two loops so that you check every enemy against every bullet.

I would also like to add that you could improve the collision detection, at the moment you are using simple bounding boxes which is fast and may be acceptable for your game but on it's own is prone to produce false positives and false negatives.

Personally, I would add another step - If the bounding box collision shows a hit then delegate to a bitwise collision detection, essentially it would work by having a 2 dimensional array of set and unset pixels for enemies and bullets. You would use the screen offsets for the bullet and the enemy and where a bullet has a bit set in it's mask you check the enemy bit mask to see if the bit is set, if it is then you have a genuine collision.

Obviously this would involve another 2 loops and the creation of bit masks for your sprites but it would be fairly optimised as the initial bounding box check would discard a lot of unnecessary checks.

Definitely worth implementing this if you can as it makes the game fairer, in fact as long as the speed of bullets and enemies are such that in a single update of the game they cannot pass through each other without hitting then it would be 100% accurate.